# xml parsing in golang (i want to access each element in the details individually )

Tags: xml, parsing, go, nested

The XML data that i want to parse is:

```
<cm>
<id>TASK_DATA_RES</id>
<task>
    <swid>3873-0</swid>
     <detail>
    <![CDATA[<execute name="EXECUTE">      
    <swid>3873</swid>
    <tskid>MONITOR0</tskid>
    <file_name>DiskStatusCheck.ps1</file_name>
    <param>/metricName::metric_3873_48 /metric::DiskStatusCheck /warn::1 /critical::1 /alert::1 /params::E:</param>
    <timeout></timeout>
    <user>test\\test</user>
    <passwd>test</passwd>   <path>https://mspnocsupport.com/downloadScript.doaction=downloadAgent&fileName=DiskStatusCheck.ps1&version=5.00</path>
    <pathtype>local</pathtype>
    <size>9147</size>
    <encoded_size>9147</encoded_size>
    <type>POWERSHELL</type>
    <outputdir></outputdir>
    <outputfile></outputfile>
    <alert>false</alert>
    <regkeypath></regkeypath>
    <regkeyval></regkeyval>
    <process></process>
    <service></service>
    <version>5.00</version>
    <asuser_flag>0</asuser_flag>
    </execute>]]>
    </detail>
</task>
</cm>
```

The corresponding structure to parse such XML documents:

```
type detail struct{
    Name string `xml:"detail>name"`
    Swid string `xml:"detail>swid"` 
    Tskid string `xml:"detail>tskid"`
    File string `xml:"detail>file"`
    Param string `xml:"detail>params"`
    User string `xml:"detail>user"`   
    Passwd string `xml:"detail>passwd"`
    Path string `xml:"detail>path"`
    Pathtype string `xml:"detail>pathtype"`
    Size int `xml:"detail>size"`
    Encode string `xml:"detail>encode"`
    Type string `xml:"detail>type"`
    Outputdir string `xml:"detail>outputdir"`
    Outputfile string `xml:"detail>outputfile"`
    Alert string `xml:"detail>alert"`
    Regkeyval string `xml:"detail>regkeyval"`
    Process string `xml:"detail>process"`   
    Service string `xml:"detail>service"`
    Version float64 `xml:"detail>version"`
    Asuser_flag string `xml:"detail>asuser_flag"`
}

type task struct{
    Swid string `xml:"swid"`
    Details []detail `xml:"Details>detail"`
}
type task_data_res struct{
    ID    string `xml:"id"`
    //Swid  string `xml:"task>swid"`
    Tasks []task `xml:"Tasks>task"` 
}
v := task_data_res{}
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(*dxml), &v)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    return
}
```

After that i want to print individual value of Detail structure  such as name,Swid etc.

Comment: The formatting makes it difficult to see what you have, what you want and what you tried.

Comment: Your var v is referring to task_data_res struct which is having ID and array of Task. And while printing you are trying to print v.SwidD, v.Tskid etc which are not part of task_data_res struct and hence you are getting error

Comment: Could you come up with a minimal (or at least a much much smaller) example of what you want to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried to parse your xml, you can find complete solution at http://play.golang.org/p/1UCaGYetzo

Comment: Thanks for the help .can you suggest me some resource to dig more into this kind of parsing and GOLANG.